# Android borders color with selector listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

I had this working perfectly, although I need to change my code to listSelector, and now I don't know how to do it in order to maintain the border on left side.

In all listview lines I had one border:
border.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E30E0E"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E3E3E3"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This sets the **left side** of each line, a border with color. But, as you can see, it has a default Solid color for background. With this code, whenever the user click on the item of the listview he doesn't understand if he has already clicked or not, because it has this solid color which doesn't change onState().

To make this working, I needed to create a listSelector with background gradients on state select plus state pressed.

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_gradient_bg"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

So, my question is: there's any way to "link" this two different piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this

```
<item android:left="5dip">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#E3E3E3"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

into the listview_gradient_bg and listview_gradient_bg_hover drawables, then link the selector to each line in the adapter.

Comment: Sorry for being so late. After all I didn't need to use the borders. Thanks anyway.